# Trying to update age value with given list

Tags: python

I am trying to update age in the given list/dictionary but I get a key error at the first name and last name parameter any help would be appreciated.

```
def create_contacts_collection():
    contacts = {}
    return contacts

def add_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, age):
    contacts[first_name, last_name] = [email, phone_number, age]

def has_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name):
    if (first_name, last_name) in contacts:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_contact_age(contacts, first_name, last_name):
    if has_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name):
        return contacts[(first_name, last_name)][2]

def update_contact_age(contacts, first_name, last_name, age):
    contacts[(first_name, last_name)][2] = age
    if update_contact_age == get_contact_age:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

It should be able to pass these tests

```
def test_add_contact():
    contacts = create_contacts_collection()
    len_before_adding = len(contacts)
    add_contact(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson', 'bjer@ice.crm', '555-267-8301',
    31)
    len_after_adding = len(contacts)

    show_results("add_contact() test 1",
                len_before_adding == 0 and len_after_adding > 0)

def test_has_contact():
    contacts = create_contacts_collection()
    add_contact(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson', 'bjer@ice.crm', '555-267-8301', 
    31)
    show_results("has_contact() test 1",
                 has_contact(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson') == True)
    show_results("has_contact() test 2",
                 has_contact(contacts, 'Jen', 'Berryson') === False)

def test_get_contact_age():
    contacts = create_contacts_collection()
    add_contact(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson', 'bjer@ice.crm', '55-267-8301', 
    31)
    show_results("get_contact_age() test 1",
                 get_contact_age(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson') == 31)
    show_results("get_contact_age() test 2",
                 get_contact_age(contacts, 'Jen', 'Berryson') == None)
```

This will be the same concept for test_get_contact_email, test_get_contact_phone_number.

```
def test_update_contact_age():
    contacts = create_contacts_collection()
    add_contact(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson', 'bjer@ice.crm', '555-267-8301', 
    31)
    show_results("update_contact_age() test 1",
                 update_contact_age(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson', 31) == True 
                 and get_contact_age(contacts, 'Ben', 'Jerryson') == 35)
    show_results("update_contact_age() test 2",
                 update_contact_age(contacts, 'Jen', 'Berryson', 72) == 
                 False)
```

Then the same concept for test_update_contact_email, test_update_ contact_phone_number.

It was able to pass all the other tests except both of the 
def test_update_contacts_age tests

Comment: Could you please copy paste your code instead of uploading screenshots.

Comment: To expand on the request for code instead of images of text; images are not searchable, nor are they accessible, so they don't make for useful questions that can be of use to people who encounter the same issue in the future.

Comment: I did as you asked

Comment: The definition of the function has_contact is missing.

Comment: Last 4 lines in `update_contact_age` don't make any sense, it is comparing two functions.

Comment: the rest should work as expected.

Comment: I am getting a Key Error for the ( first_name, last_name) though

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is working fine

```
    def create_contacts_collection():
      contacts = {}
      return contacts

    def add_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, age):
      contacts[first_name, last_name] = [email, phone_number, age]

    def has_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name):
      if (first_name, last_name) in contacts:
              return True
      else:
              return False

    def get_contact_age(contacts, first_name, last_name):
      if has_contact(contacts, first_name, last_name):
              return contacts[(first_name, last_name)][2]

    def update_contact_age(contacts, first_name, last_name, age):
      contacts[(first_name, last_name)][2] = age
      if update_contact_age == get_contact_age:
              return False
      else:
              return True
    w = create_contacts_collection()
    add_contact(w,"abcd","efgh","a@b.com","0123","21")
    print(has_contact(w,"abcd","efgh"))
    print(get_contact_age(w,"abcd","efgh"))
    update_contact_age(w,"abcd","efgh",80)
    print(has_contact(w,"abcd","efgh"))

    # OUTPUT
    True
    21
    True
```

You will get error if you try to update name or surname in a contact because you have stored contact on the basis of that field and while updating you are trying to find to find the new contact which does not exists. Otherwise if you will update the age of contact, that will work fine.

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't trying to print these should just return the results I'm actually trying to run it through a test code

Comment: I have just added the test code as well to see if someone can tell what's wrong with test_update_contacts_age.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the format of my list?